# How to test a Flowable that has a subscription?

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java

I know about `TestSubscriber` and it's really useful, however sometimes there's logic relating to a subscription to a `Flowable`, and that needs to be tested.

Example:

```
Flowable.just("Hello world!")
  .subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s),
    error -> {
      handler.handle("Scanning files");
    },
    () -> {
      handler.handle("Scanning files");
    }
  );
```

If I want to ensure `handler.handle("Scanning files")` was called, what is the best way of doing this - is the only way a "traditional" mocking approach?

The issue with mocking is that if the Flowable is more complicated, including execution across multiple threads, it becomes difficult to simulate time advances etc, which is a great reason to use `TestSubscriber`.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to parameterise the `Scheduler` and pass a `TestScheduler` when the test fixture is set-up.

This way you can use the `advanceTimeBy` et al methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Mockito as usual to verify that your handler was called :

```
verify(handler, only()).handle(any());
```

The problem is how you you can be sure that the line before is called after the `suscribe` method was ended ?

I can see two options :

- Calling `blockingSubscribe` instead of `subscribe`
- Change all the thread-handlers to the main thread (by using `RxJavaPlugins`)

Maybe you can put Thread.sleep() before the verification but it I don't think it's  a good idea.

`TestSubscriber` and `TestScheduler` are the best way to test Observables for me.